# Set values to one jLabel and textBoxes while sorting is running

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

```
public void QUICKSORT(int[] A, int p, int r)  {
if(p < r)    
 {
    q=PARTITION(A,p,r);
    labelPartitionPoint.setText("Partition point = "+q);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    QUICKSORT(A,p,q-1);
    QUICKSORT(A,q+1,r);
  } 
}
```

Comment: _Don't_ sleep on the EDT; _do_ see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Hmm... what is the question, really? What obstacles have you encountered, what means have you tried to overcome it?

Comment: Also, `lblPartitionPoint.setText("Partition point = "+q);` will keep overriding the existing label value on every recursion! Have an array of `lblPartitionPoint` and set each label, 1 by 1, in every recursion, if its that important!

Comment: can u explain with simple example how to set values to lable each recursion ..

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing that in an external thread, you have to schedule the update of the Swing components state within EDT with Swing utilities *invokeLater* (or *invokeAndWait*).

```
public void QUICKSORT(int[] A, int p, int r)  {
if(p < r)    
 {
    q=PARTITION(A,p,r);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            lblPartitionPoint.setText("Partition point = "+q);
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    QUICKSORT(A,p,q-1);
    QUICKSORT(A,q+1,r);
  } 
}
```

Comment: tx @fortran i got that ..